# Transit visa at Frankfurt international airport

Tags: airports, frankfurt

I am traveling New Delhi to San Francisco and back to New Delhi by Lufthansa. In my return, I will break the journey at Frankfurt International Airport to fly to UK by a different airline, and stay there for a week. I have the USA and the UK visas. After a week-long stay in UK, I'll fly back to Frankfurt International Airport and take my Lufthansa flight back to New Delhi. Do I need any Schengen or airport transit visa to do the above?

Comment: Not yet an answer, but probably already helpful: The airline will check that you have the needed visa to enter the country of destination before you may board your SFO->FRA flight. As for them (if the flight to the UK is on a different ticket), Frankfurt is not just a layover point, they will want to see a Schengen visa, which you cannot provide. Now they *may* be satisfied with you having an onwards ticket, but there is no guarantee. Also, if you have checked luggage, you will need to collect it landside to re-check it. You need a Schengen visa for that - an airport transit visa will not do.

Comment: The UK flight is on another airline but was it booked together with the others through Lufthansa or perhaps a travel agent?

Answer (score 3):

As far as the rules are concerned, Indian citizens require an “airport transit visa” for airside transit in Germany but you are exempted from this requirement by your other visas. Either the UK or USA visa are enough for that, *and it's not required to be on your way to the country in question* (i.e. holding a valid US visa is enough to exempt you from the airside transit visa requirement when flying to the UK or anywhere else).

The question is therefore whether you will require a regular Schengen visa or not. That depends what you mean by “break the journey”. If you have a ticket to Frankfurt and need to leave the transit lounge to pick up your luggage and check in on the next flight, then you will need it. On the other hand, if you have no luggage or somehow manage to have it checked through or otherwise taken care of, you might be able transit without a visa.

In any case, as @DCTLib explained in his comment, the airline will want to ensure you have the necessary visas before letting you board the flight in India so it's best to check with them. Flying on another airline is not an issue *per se* but if you have booked the ticket to the UK separately and it looks to Lufthansa as if you would spend a week in Germany, you will likely run into some difficulties.